# Sum of the elements in a row of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

```
Samplespacedice2 = 
 Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2}]
Mattwodice = MatrixForm[Samplespacedice2]
```

The above gives a matrix as follows:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 3 \\
 1 & 4 \\
 1 & 5 \\
 1 & 6 \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 \\
 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 4 \\
 2 & 5 \\
 2 & 6 \\
 2 & 2 \\
 3 & 1 \\
 3 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 3 & 5 \\
 3 & 6 \\
 3 & 3 \\
 4 & 1 \\
 4 & 2 \\
 4 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 \\
 4 & 6 \\
 4 & 4 \\
 5 & 1 \\
 5 & 2 \\
 5 & 3 \\
 5 & 4 \\
 5 & 6 \\
 5 & 5 \\
 6 & 1 \\
 6 & 2 \\
 6 & 3 \\
 6 & 4 \\
 6 & 5 \\
 6 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Here how can I check for the rows that are giving a sum of elements greater than  7 through a code?

Comment: `Samplespacedice2//Pick[#,UnitStep[7-Total[#,{2}]],0]&`

Answer (score 5):

```
selected = Select[Total@# > 7 &] @ Samplespacedice2
```

> ```
>  {{2, 6}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 6},
>    {5, 5}, {6, 2}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 5}, {6, 6}}
> ```

Comment: Is there a possibility to find the number of sets in which first element is 2 and second is not 4?

Comment: @Jasmine - either `Length@Select[Samplespacedice2, #[[1]] == 2 && #[[2]] != 4 &]` or `Count[Samplespacedice2, {2, _?(# != 4 &)}]`

Comment: @Jasmine, you can also do `Count[{2, Except[4]}]@Samplespacedice2`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the ResourceFunction [`SelectPermutations`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SelectPermutations)

```
ResourceFunction["SelectPermutations"][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2},
  Total /* GreaterThan[7]]
```

> ```
>  {{2, 6}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 4}, {5, 3}, {5, 4},
>   {5, 6}, {5, 5}, {6, 2}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 5}, {6, 6}}
> ```